# Why does querying system restore points via WMI work in Windows 7, but not Windows 10?

Tags: c#, wmi

When I need to test WMI code prior to implementing it, I use [WMI Code Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572). It's a bit old, but it seems to work well.

I'm trying to get a list of the restore points on a PC so that I can show the user this information. When I run the code generated from the code creator on Windows 10, I get 0 restore points even though I have 5 setup. When I run it on Windows 7, it shows all of the restore points.

Any ideas why this doesn't work on Windows 10?

```
try
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\DEFAULT", 
        "SELECT * FROM SystemRestore"); 

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("SystemRestore instance");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("SequenceNumber: {0}", queryObj["SequenceNumber"]);
    }
}
catch (ManagementException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
}
```

Comment: In supported operating system part, neither Win7 nor Win10 exist. I'm surprised it works on Win7 honestly. But really, this is old. It seems published in `9/12/2012`. It is _too_ normal to be unreliable with Win10.

Comment: @SonerGönül I realized the app was old. But I always thought that WMI *should* work on any version of Windows. But maybe not? I'll have to see if any WMI code works in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a few months old, but hopefully this will still help someone.

You can enumerate restore points in Windows (including Win 10) by using ManagementObjects instead of attempting to run the query yourself:

```
ManagementScope ManScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\root\default");
ManagementPath ManPath = new ManagementPath("SystemRestore");
ObjectGetOptions ManOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
ManagementClass ManClass = new ManagementClass(ManScope, ManPath, ManOptions);

foreach (ManagementObject mo in ManClass.GetInstances())
{
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

Each ManagementObject represents an instance of SystemRestore, so you can now easily retrieve any of its five properties like so:

```
var description = mo["Description"].ToString();
```

Accessing properties of ManagementObjects this ways returns an object, so you'll still have to cast the value to the appropriate type.

Note also that the GetInstances() method returns a ManagementObjectCollection which allows you to retrieve an enumerator but does not support indexing. So if you need to do more than simply enumerate the restore points you may have to copy them to another data structure.

Good luck!